# different images from different point of view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want different images to be displayed from different point of view. For the whole concept explaination please look at the images. they explain my idea/query!

As in the first image you see that there are three people at different angle looking at the monitor. Now i want the webcam to track the eyes and show the particular defined image to the user> For example: If user is at 45 degree angle then show image1.png

Depending upon the user's prespective of watching. The computer should show the image.

(the lady is the game character for representation purpose)

Can you please guide me on what steps can be taken to accomplish this? Is there any plugin available for unity that tracks faces? Please guide me

Also thanks for the compliments on my sketching skills xD

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: You are asking for someone on SO to write you an eye tracking API?

Comment: please inline your images instead of posting links to third party website

Comment: You want that, that's what I get. But what is your question? Have you started working on your algorithm and are stuck anywhere?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow is not really meant to recommend plugins, since the choice is usually opinion based so there is no exact answer.

That being said, on of the most common used API for computer vision (meaning interpreting images, including face recognition) is **OpenCV**, so that could be a good start for you to look at that.

And fortunately for you, there is a Unity plugin for **[OpenCV](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-for-unity-21088)**

It is too broad to give you more details about how it works here. You should try to make it work, and if you have a problem with your code, open a new question with the code portion that you struggle with.

PS: nice sketching skills

Comment: Thanks for you'r helpful recommendation!
PS: xD IKR, my sketching skills are dope,.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps easier option would be to use Kinect
(trying to detect face or eyes from that far might be shaky?)

With Kinect you can get skeletons for multiple people, and getting the angle between target and those kinect avatars would be easy.

If there is no space to put kinect in good position,
could consider placing it on the ceiling above (and then use depth data only to detect people in its view)

Only issue is that apparently Microsoft has stopped Windows kinect support,
so you would need to find 2nd hand versions.. (Unity Asset store still has some kinect plugins and examples available)
https://www.polygon.com/2018/1/2/16842072/xbox-one-kinect-adapter-out-of-stock-production-ended

Or look for kinect alternatives that work with unity, try RealSense cameras:
https://www.intel.sg/content/www/xa/en/architecture-and-technology/realsense-overview.html

Comment: I already have kinect. But the thing is that i cant put kinect in my device and sell it. Cause kinect would turn out to be more costlier than the product im making itself XD. Can you guide on how we can change the images according to the viewer's angle?